# How to determine if a Javascript Number is in single-precision range?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion, webidl

According to the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value), Javascript number values correspond a to double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value.

For a WebIDL validator I'm currently working on, I need to be able to figure out if a given number value can be converted to a [WebIDL float](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-float) type, i.e. if it can be represented as a finite single precision 32-bit IEEE 754 value.

I've currently settled on the following approach:

```
validate: function(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'number' || !Number.isFinite(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (value === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    var view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));

    view.setFloat32(0, value);

    var converted = view.getFloat32(0);
    var relativeError = Math.abs(value - converted) / value;

    return relativeError < Number.EPSILON;
}
```

In essence, what I'm doing is:

1. Wrap a [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) around a 4 byte [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).
2. Store the `Number` value as a 32 bit float in the buffer.
3. Get the converted number back out of the buffer.
4. Calculate the relative error between the original value and the converted value.
5. Check whether the relative error is smaller than the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for floating point numbers, using [`Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON).

A couple of comments:

- I'm implementing this as part of a Chrome extension, browser compatibility is not really an issue.
- Yes, I have read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). My eyes have yet to stop bleeding.

Is the above logic sound for what I'm trying to achieve? Is it overkill? Is there a more idiomatic, elegant or performant way to do this?

**Update**

I have in the meantime figured out that the above approach is incorrect. It will fail for a wide range of values such as `1.001`, `3.14159`, and so on. Changing the epsilon value to the machine epsilon for 32-bit floats (2<sup>−23</sup>) is on the other hand too permissive and allows values like `16777217`.

Still looking for a good solution, but currently going with the function below that just checks the integer upper and lower bounds (2<sup>24</sup> and -(2<sup>24</sup>)).

```
validate: function(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && Number.isFinite(value)
            && value >= -16777216 && value <= 16777216;
}
```

Comment: You could create a buffer and a 64-bit view of it, and then check the low bits.

Comment: can `Float32Array.from([n])[0]` simplify your routine?

Comment: @dandavis Maybe a little. `Float32Array.of(n)` would be even better if I went down that route.

Comment: or `Math.fround()` to do the conversion all in one step.... https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/11/07/efficient-float32-arithmetic-in-javascript/

Comment: If you accepted a string you could simply check if the number has no more than 6 significant digits.

Comment: @zerkms that won't work: e.g. the closest single precision number to 1.1 is 1.100000023841858 when converted to a double

Comment: @SimonByrne yep, now I see what you mean. I missed this critical part of the question: "as a **finite** single precision"

Comment: @zerkms The **finite** is only there to exclude the `NaN`, `+Infinity`, and `-Infinity` values.

Comment: @zerkms try `Math.fround(1.1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're using ECMAScript 6, you can use [`Math.fround`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.fround) to check if it's a single-precision number:

```
function isfloat32(x) {
  return isNaN(x) || x == Math.fround(x);
}
```

UPDATE: I missed the part about a [WebIDL float](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-float) being finite (i.e. not an Inf or NaN). In that case,

```
function isfloat32(x) {
  return isFinite(x) && x == Math.fround(x);
}
```